# Is this code from STM32 FATFS User manual (um1721 ) correct?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, embedded-resource

I am going through a codebase, that uses the FatFS library by Chan and probably developed using the CubeMX code generator. I can see the code given below there. It is also described in [STM32 user manual UM1721](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1721-developing-applications-on-stm32cube-with-fatfs-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

A structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{ 
  uint8_t                 is_initialized[_VOLUMES];
  Diskio_drvTypeDef       *drv[_VOLUMES];
  __IO uint8_t            nbr;

}Disk_drvTypeDef;
```

`disk` is A global variable defined as:

```
Disk_drvTypeDef  disk = {0};
```

A function is defined as follows:

```
uint8_t FATFS_LinkDriver(Diskio_drvTypeDef *drv, char *path)
{
  uint8_t ret = 1;
  uint8_t DiskNum = 0;
  if(disk.nbr <= _VOLUMES)
  {
    disk.is_initialized[disk.nbr] = 0;
    disk.drv[disk.nbr] = drv;  
    DiskNum = disk.nbr++;
    path[0] = DiskNum + '0';
    path[1] = ':';
    path[2] = '/';
    path[3] = 0;
    ret = 0;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

My question is what happens when the `disk.nbr == _VOLUMES`, and I call the `FATFS_LinkDriver` function. Won't it try to place `drv` into `disk.drv[_VOLUMES]`? But the `disk.drv` is of size `_VOLUMES`. So shouldn't the maximum index be 1 less than that? Am I missing something?

Comment: It does seem like `if(disk.nbr <= _VOLUMES)` should be `if(disk.nbr <  _VOLUMES)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code invokes undefined behavior in this line:

```
disk.drv[disk.nbr] = drv;
```

when `disk.nbr == _VOLUMES`.

> Is this code from STM32 FATFS User manual (um1721 ) correct?

No, it is not. General remark - there is no guarantee that the code found in the documentation will be correct.